# qrcode-Package: escaping special characters

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, qrcode

**What I want**

A qr-code which generates the following link:

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test%20test&utm_term=test&utm_content=test

**What I get**

https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=#2?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test%20test&utm_term=test&utm_content=test

**The problem**

`#2` doesn't render to `en`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcommand{\myqrcode}[2]{%
    \draw (#1) node {\qrcode[height=5cm]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=\#2?utm_source=test\&utm_medium=test\&utm_campaign=test\%20test\&utm_term=test\&utm_content=test}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \myqrcode{0,0}{en}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#2` instead of `\#2`?

Comment: Oh! I escaped too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\#` if you want to get a literal `#` in the URL. In this case you want TeX to substitute a parameter, so you need

```
qrcode?lang=#2?utm_source=test\&utm_medium=test
```

(`&` should indeed be escaped).